# How to display stock quantity only for simple products?

Tags: magento2.2, qty

I want to display stock quantity only for simple products. For that, I added some code and it's working fine for simple products. But the thing is it's also showing quantity for other types of products like configurable.

here is the code I added
app/code/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Smartwave\Porto\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    protected $_objectManager;
    private $_registry;
    protected $_filterProvider;
    private $_checkedPurchaseCode;
    private $_messageManager;
    protected $_configFactory;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


     public function getStockQty($product)
    {
        return $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->getQty();
    }
}
```

app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>

<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>

    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <div class="stock available" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span><?php echo $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data')->getStockQty($_product);?></span>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
            <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability:') ?></span>
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this below code in your if else condition :

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple') : ?>
            <div class="stock available" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
                <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability:') ?></span>
                <span><?php echo $this->helper('Smartwave\Porto\Helper\Data')->getStockQty($_product);?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
        <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability:') ?></span>
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below condition to display stock quantity if its simple product only

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple'){
//your code
}
```

It will return configurable or simple